# HADOOP HTTPFS : giving error "User: ubuntu is not allowed to impersonate ubuntu" while accessing the application through Http

Tags: java, ubuntu, hadoop, hdfs, bigdata

I have installed hadoop 1.0.4 on my cluster, of 1 master and 3 slaves,
and now I am installing HTTPFS(hadoop-hdfs-httpfs-0.20.2-cdh3u5-SNAPSHOT) to access the HDFS contents using http protocol,

I am able to access the normal page through it

```
curl -i "http://myhost:14000"
```

its works fine :)

but If I tried to access HDFS then its giving me error(ubantu is my user) :(

```
curl -i "http://myhost:14000/webhdfs/v1?user.name=ubantu&op=OPEN"
```

error:

```
    {"RemoteException":{"message":"User: ubantu is not allowed to impersonate ubantu",
"exception":"RemoteException","javaClassName":"org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException"}}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please ignore my edit to this, I misread the question and thought that you had misspelled the linux distro's ubuntu's name, when actually ubantu is your user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolved this issue, As I havent added my user ubantu into the hadoop user groups.
added user ubantu into the hadoop group and
updated property in core-site.xml as

```
     <property>
        <name>hadoop.proxyuser.myhttpfsuser.hosts</name>
        <value>httpfs-host.foo.com</value>
     </property>
     <property>
        <name>hadoop.proxyuser.myhttpfsuser.groups</name>
        <value>hadoop</value>
     </property>
```

now its working fine.

Comment: what is acctualy should go at  <value>httpfs-host.foo.com</value>  ?

Answer (score 2):

Did you configure core-site.xml as described here: http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-hdfs-httpfs/ServerSetup.html

where #HTTPFSUSER# is the user that starts the httpfs daemon? (presumably "ubantu")?

After doing this, restart the HDFS daemons.

Answer (score 1):

Simple googling shows someone else with the same error that did not bounce the servers to get the configuration changes.

https://groups.google.com/a/cloudera.org/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/cdh-user/dSJP-a_Lcqo

Comment: Thanks for answer bmucklow, but I already did a lot of R&D on this and the site you suggested I already visited there but still the same error.